# iOS incomplete fonts (Checkmark)?

Tags: ios, fonts

I try to display a checkmark symbol like this:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    [@"✓" drawInRect: CGRectInset(ovalRect, 0/116.0*width, 11/116.0*width) withAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[[UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue" size: 80.0/116.0*width], paragraphStyle, [UIColor orangeColor]] forKeys:@[NSFontAttributeName, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, NSForegroundColorAttributeName]]];
```

On http://iosfonts.com the symbol looks just like I want it for Helvetica Neue. However, on the device/ simulator it looks completely different. I found about 3 fonts where it looked different but for the other 20 fonts I tested it always looked the same, always different from http://iosfonts.com. How can I find out how the checkmark symbol would look in different iOS fonts? I don't want to try them all out by hand.

Comment: Why not? :) That wouldn't be hard. Copy-paste the list of fonts into a tableview startup project. Set the font to the appropriate member of the list in the cell return function. You could be done in 10 minutes. :)

Comment: @StevenFisher It seems like there are actually only a few different checkmarks available, on my mac the fonts do have different checkmarks though.

Comment: I suggest you post the function you provided and the way you built the project as an answer (if you can, not sure what the minimum reputation is!) and accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone else has font problems, here is the code to display text in all available fonts in an `UITableView`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Fill NSMutableArray fonts with all available fonts
    fonts = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
    NSArray *fontNames;
    NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
    for (indFamily = 0; indFamily < [familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
    {
        fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:[familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
        for (indFont = 0; indFont < [fontNames count]; ++indFont)
        {
            [fonts addObject:[fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]];
        }
    }
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *font = [fonts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"✓ %@", font]];
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:font size:16]];
    return cell;
}
```